Use admin user for database setup and app user for runnning the application in Springboot Tests with @Sql
I'm trying to automate an integration test on my backend application against an oracle database. I can bring up a separate docker container with the schema and i can connect to it using the schema owner no problem. My application has a special user (user_app, different from the schema owner) to connect to the database, with limited grants. The profile for normal opertation and deployment looks like this:
spring:
  
  # OracleDB connection settings
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XEPDB1?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    username: user_app
    password: user_app

Now when I try to test the application using @SpringbootTest I would do something like this in my test profile using the schema owner, otherwise I stumble upon grant issues:
spring:
  
  # OracleDB connection settings
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XEPDB1?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    username: user
    password: user

And something like this to set up the testcase:
@Sql(scripts = {
    "classpath:/sql/clean_db.sql",
    "classpath:/sql/setup_test_cases.sql"
})
@Sql(scripts = {
        "classpath:/sql/clean_db.sql"
    },
    executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD
)
class APITest {

    @Test
    void testAPI()
    {
        // Call some api method to test against the database
        someAPIMethod();
    }
}

I would like to run the application with the normal limited user (user_app) but run the @Sql parts with the schema owner (user) instead of using the schema owner as I´m doing now for testing. How should I do this?
I tried to add @SqlConfig(dataSource = "schemaOwnerDatasource") by setting up bith datasources in yaml profile:
spring:
  
  # OracleDB connection settings
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XEPDB1?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    username: user_app
    password: user_app
  schema-owner-datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XEPDB1?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    username: user
    password: user

And then adding the beans to a @Configuration class:
@Configuration
class TestDatasourceConfiguration {

@Primary
@Bean(name = "userAppDatasource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource userAppDatasource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "schemaOwnerDatasource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.schema-owner-datasource")
public DataSource shcemaOwnerDatasource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

}

But then I´m hit with errors on the application failing to connect to the database. What I am missing?

I did not understand two things - do you want to execute tests as a privileged user where as run application for normal user? And second - what is an error text?

Anyway I think using profiles should help. Please see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/external-config.html#features.external-config.files.profile-specific

@Alex : Profiles do help, I'm using one for running and one for testing as stated. The issue is: the SQL to clean up the tables and create the test cases should be run as the user with privileges (over the schema) and the application should be run as the user with lower privileges. A problem I don't have when running the application since there is no changes to be made into the db. For that i tried using two datasources, but springboot has a limitation on that i guess. The error is something like the entityManager is not initialized or can't be found.

Here is my configuration for two datasources, may be it helps
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.postgresql")
    public DataSourceProperties postgresqlDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.clickhouse")
    public DataSourceProperties clickhouseDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource postgresqlDataSource() {
        return postgresqlDataSourceProperties()
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource clickhouseDataSource() {
        return clickhouseDataSourceProperties()
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate clickhouseJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("clickhouseDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate postgresqlJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("postgresqlDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

 }

and in application.yml
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
  datasource:
    postgresql:
      url: ${POSTGRESQL_URL}
      username: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
      password: ${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    clickhouse:
      url: ${CLICKHOUSE_URL}
      username: ${CLICKHOUSE_USER}
      password: ${CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD}
      driver-class-name: com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver

Then we can use
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("clickhouseJdbcTemplate")
    protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

for accessing ClickHouse and
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("postgresqlJdbcTemplate")
    protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

for accessing Postgres

This one helped (at least the error changed) but doesn´t answer my original question. I'm trying to connect to the same database with two different users in a @SpringbootTest run.
I'm getting duplicated tables detected by the schema validator: " Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.SchemaExtractionException: More than one table found in namespace (, ) : "

As it is hibernate error we have to look what is the hibernate part of yours spring context. Did you set hibernate:ddl-auto:none ?

I have hibernate: ddl-auto: validate

Did you tried to set it to none as it is in my example?

Hibernate seems does not know what table to validate because there are two
